# Extending custom template tags to other templates in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, tags

Is there a way to load custom template tags in one template file and extend that to all others?

I am using `{% load subdomainurls %}` template tag from the [django-subdomains library](https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in a project where content is dependent on a subdomain (company.example.com). These custom tags include "url" which takes a subdomain argument, `{% url 'namespace:name' subdomain='company' %}`. I am trying to load these custom tags in `base.html` so that I do not have to load them in every template.

`base.html`:

```
    {% load subdomainurls %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
      ---snip---
      <body>
        <h1><a href="{% url 'orgs:home' subdomain=request.subdomain %}">App Title</a></h1>

        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}

      </body>
     </html>
```

However, when I then extend `base.html`, I do not get the custom url tag, but rather the default.

`login_page.html`:

```
{% extends 'orgs/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h3>Login a subdomain user:</h3>
    <form action="{% url 'users:loginpage' subdomain=request.subdomain %}" method = 'post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{form.as_table}}
        </table>
        <button name="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

This produces an error from **url** trying to pass an argument to the url_conf that does not match any patterns. In order to get the template url to function properly, I have to include `{% load subdomainurls %}` in each template. I've tried loading the custom tags between the body tags and between `{% block content %} {% endblock content %}` in `base.html`, but I get the same result.

**Edit to include settings.py**:

````
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '#############################################'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.168.48','localhost', '.example.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #third-party apps
    'subdomains',
    'phone_field',
    #example.com custom apps
    'sdUsers',
    'orgs',
    'register',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'subdomains.middleware.SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

#Customization parameters for Subdomains and custom user model

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'sdUsers.sdUser'
SITE_ID = 1
ROOT_URLCONF = 'example.urls'
SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS = {
    None:'example.urls',
    'www':'example.urls',
}

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'example.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbExample',
        'USER': '#####',
        'PASSWORD':'###########',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306'
        }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/' ```

`project->urls.py`
````

````
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/',include('sdUsers.urls', namespace='users')),
    path('',include('orgs',namespace='orgs')),
    path('register/', include('register.urls',namespace='register')),
]```
````

app->urls.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, re_path
    from . import views

    app_name = 'register'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.redbook, name='redbook'),
        path('entry/', views.service_entry,name='entry'),
        path('entry/<int:entryid>', views.edit_entry, name='edit'),
        re_path(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.redbook, name='redbook_year'), 
        ]
```

Comment: Please also post your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Sure. Included in the edited original post. Thank you.

Comment: Please also post your `urls.py` file.

Comment: The subdomain argument in the template tag does not get passed to the urls.py file. It can be used to point to a different subdomain of the same site. So, a user might be on their-company.example.com/homepage and click on a link that gets them to support.example.com/homepage. The custom template tag from Django-subdomains adds that functionality. If subdomain is not included, it will create the url to the current subdomain. (btw, thanks for the suggested edits. Kinda new here on stack. I think I accidentally overwrote one of your edits towards the bottom of the page.

Comment: I've never used this library (though I might have a need to soon).  At  https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#resolving-named-urls-in-templates it says:  An easy way to ensure this functionality is available is to add `django.core.context_processors.request()` is in your `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` list.  You could try that.

Comment: I don't think that's available in Django 2.2+, I think it has become `django.template.context_processors.request`. The functionality of the custom tags works great when I load them in each template. It just doesn't extend from another template.